# SQL list of table contents with duplicate values summed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table... call it `TABLE_A`:

| item_key | user_name | loan_type | loan_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jsmith | 1234 | 1000 |
| 2 | jdoe | 5678 | 2000 |
| 3 | jsmith | 1234 | 500 |
| 4 | pparker | 1234 | 750 |
| 5 | jdoe | 4321 | 1000 |
| 6 | jsmith | 8765 | 2000 |

I need a SQL statement that will yield this result:

| user_name | loan_type | loan_amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jdoe | 5678 | 2000 |
| jdoe | 4321 | 1000 |
| jsmtih | 1234 | 1500 |
| jsmith | 8765 | 2000 |
| pparker | 1234 | 750 |

Where loan_amount for the same user_name and loan_type (except for types '5678' and '8765', which should not be summed).
The loan_amounts in rows 1 and 3 were summed (and the rows merged) because the had the same user_name and loan_type. The rest of the rows differed in user_name or loan_type values.

I can group and sum...

```
SELECT 
    user_name, loan_type, 
    SUM(loan_amt) AS loan_amt 
FROM 
    TABLE_A 
GROUP BY 
    user_name, loan_type;
```

However, it does not discriminate by the `loan_type` and multiple rows of '5678' and '8765' with the same `user_name` and `loan_type` would also be summed.

I tried adding a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
    user_name, loan_type, 
    CASE 
        WHEN loan_type = '5678' SUM(loan_amt) AS loan_amt
        WHEN loan_type = '8756' SUM(loan_amt) AS loan_amt 
        ELSE loan_type
    END AS loan_amt
FROM
    TABLE_A 
GROUP BY 
    user_name, loan_type;
```

But, it doesn't work because for the 'ELSE' to function properly it must be SUMmed.

Answer (score -1):

As too often happens... just writing out the problem, led me to the simple answer. So, I went ahead and posted this, just in case it might be useful to others.

The CASE version works great when the ELSE is also summed...

```
ELSE SUM(loan_type)
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense though, why summarizing loan_type

Comment: Now all branches of the `CASE` expression return the same thing (`SUM(loan_type)`), which makes it a no-op. It don't understand which problem you are trying to solve, your original query looks good (without the `CASE` expression) for your data and expected results.

Comment: i think what you want is  select user_name loan_type, sum(loan_amt) from someTable group by user_name, loan_type, case when loan_type IN ('5678','8756') THEN item_key else -1 END

Comment: If i understand, he wants every 5678, 8756 row to be displayed separately for some reason and never be grouped with other such rows

Comment: You are right, my example (as illustrated above) is incorrect and unclear. I apologize, and thank you for pointing it out.